# A basic OO design question - Should we instantiante a DAO on another DAO ? (zend)

Tags: oop, zend-framework

Providing that I have the following on:

**TeamGamesDao** Class:

```
    public function listOfTeams() {
        $select = $this->select()
          ->from(array('t'=>'teams'), array('cod_team','name','score'));
        $rows = $this->fetchAll($select);
        foreach($rows as &$row) {
          $total = ????????????????????????????????
          $done = $this->_getTeamsGamesDone($row['teamid']);
            $row['percentage_of_games_done'] = $total > 0 ? ($done*100)/$total : 0);
        }

        return $rows;
    } 

private function _getTeamsGamesDone($teamid) {
   /* ... */
}
```

And that, the ???????? is a value that will came from **GamesDao Class** by a public method there defined like: `getTotalGames();`

How should we call it on listOfTeams() ? 
Should we instantiate it or call it statically, or some third possibility?

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to be aware of here is that the call to `getTotalGames()` on the GameDao class occurs within the `foreach($rows as &$row)` loop. Assuming that the `getTotalGames()` method does its own db query, then you'd be hitting the db once within each iteration of the loop, which is generally frowned upon.

An alternative might be to rewrite the method to perform a join on the games and teams tables that includes a `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` to get the per-team game counts.

Then you'd still be able to iterate through your teams, but it would only hit the db a single time.

Answer (score 1):

In short, using static methods makes polymorphism impossible. As a result, it makes code harder to test (isolating dependencies) and less extensible in general. On the other hand, if the DAO instance was passed to the class as a dependency, then it would make testing easier and allow for swapping different implementations of the DAO at runtime.

Comment: Not follow all because I'm newbie on those matters, are you saying that  instantiation could be a better approach on this case? So, shoud I do: $gamesDao = new gamesDao(); and then: $total = $gamesDao->getTotalGames(); ? (this is indeed, a very basic question "à mon avis"); Thanks a lot again. :)